# "The point of" vs "the sense of"

Tags: word-meaning, difference, word-difference

In my native language *the point of* and *the sense of* may be translated in the same way. Is there any difference between them in English? I would like to look at examples. For instance,

> What is the point of the feature?

and

> What is the sense of the feature?

Are these two sentences correct at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The point of* and *The sense of* may mean the same in some context and different in other. It depends for what they are used.

One of the meanings of [*sense (meaning #7)*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sense) and [*point* (def #3)](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/point) is *purpose*. So, **if** you, in your example sentence, are asking about *what is the reason behind or purpose of keeping this feature,* both the words can be used.

Note that they are **not** interchangeable in all cases.

> 'In what *sense* you are using the word (Here, I'm talking about in what context, meaning...)?' *won't look natural if you write* - 'In what *point* you are using the word?'

There are many meanings of both the words and as I said, either can be used if you mean 'purpose' or 'reason'.

However, to sound natural, I'd prefer...

> What is the purpose of the feature?